# Query for 'Enabled Visualforce Pages' on a Force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites

EDIT: I couldn't get the MetadataAPI to agree with me in time to turn this in, as this is just supposed to be a quick page and not take long.  Here's what I ended up doing:

```
public List<ApexPage> pagesList {get; set;}
private void BuildPagesList() {
    User guestUser = [SELECT ProfileId FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT GuestUserId FROM Site WHERE Name = 'MY_PAGE_NAME')];
    PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE ProfileId = :guestUser.ProfileId];
    List<ApexPage> enabledPages = [SELECT Id, Name, MasterLabel 
                                    FROM ApexPage 
                                    WHERE Id IN 
                                        (SELECT SetupEntityId FROM SetupEntityAccess 
                                            WHERE SetupEntityType = 'ApexPage' AND ParentId = :ps.Id) 
                                    ORDER BY MasterLabel ASC];

    pagesList = new List<ApexPage>();

    for (ApexPage page : enabledPages) {
        if (!excludePagesFromList.contains(page.Name)) {
            System.debug('Page ' + page.Name + ' is enabled');
            pagesList.add(page);
        }
    }
}
private Set<String> excludePagesFromList = new Set<String> {'BandwidthExceeded','Exception','FileNotFound','ForgotPassword','ForgotPasswordConfirm','InMaintenance','SiteLogin','SiteRegister','SiteRegisterConfirm','SiteTemplate','Unauthorized'};
```

I would like to query all of the Visualforce Pages assigned to a specific force.com Site.

Once a Site is created, a user can select Visualforce pages to be available through that site.

Example:
[image]

I am wanting to query what Visualforce Pages are available on a given site, something similar to:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Description, (SELECT Name, Label FROM AssignedPages) FROM Site WHERE Name = 'MySiteName'
```

I know "AssignedPages" is not a valid relationship name.  I am trying to get a sublist of the assigned Visualforce pages, and I can't find how that relationship works.

Comment: Hi Zach, welcome to SFSE. As in its current form, its not very clear as what are you trying to achieve. Could you please elaborate and clarify what exactly do you need here and what is your issue? This seems more as a dashboard reflecting the current build status rather than anything specific related to Salesforce. You may like to take a look on [*How to Ask*](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [*edit your question*](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/239083/edit) to provide details here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can obtain the Visualforce pages that are enabled for any given Site by querying the `SetupEntityAccess` table for the Profile of the Site's Guest User. Here's how it can go. (Unfortunately, there are several more steps than a simple subquery).

```
User guestUser = [SELECT ProfileId FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT GuestUserId FROM Site WHERE Name = 'MY_SITE_NAME')];
PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE ProfileId = :guestUser.ProfileId];
List<ApexPage> enabledPages = [SELECT Id, Name FROM ApexPage WHERE Id IN (SELECT SetupEntityId FROM SetupEntityAccess WHERE SetupEntityType = 'ApexPage' AND ParentId = :ps.Id)];

for (ApexPage a : enabledPages) {
    System.debug('Page ' + a.Name + ' is enabled');
}
```

This will output all of the enabled Visualforce pages for the Site, regardless of whether or not they're actually in use.

As far as I'm aware, the only way to access which pages are configured with specific roles for the site (e.g., the home page and various error pages) is to retrieve the `CustomSite` Metadata API entity. You *can* do that in Apex; see the [`apex-mdapi`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) wrapper, where you'll see the list of returned `CustomSite` properties around line [7774](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls#L7774) of `MetadataService.cls`.

Comment: David, thanks so much! I have this working, pulling all the pages.  I am familiar with the metadata service...I'll work that up and post a full solution tomorrow.